How to add a python variable to a regex.finditer object allowing mismatches
I am trying to use the following code to look for a pattern allowing mismatches but I don't know how to add a variable to the string.
string_patterns = ["AAGG", "TTGGA"]
reference_seq = "ATGATGCTGATGAGGGGGAAATTTT"

for m in regex.finditer("(ACCGACAGCCACCCGAAGA){s<=1}", reference_seq):
   print(f"{m.group()}: [{m.start()}-{m.end()}]")

How can I effectively pass the list elements instead of (ACCGACAGCCACCCGAAGA)?

Have you considered f strings?

I have but it didn't work. Would it be something like f"({variable}){s<=1}" ?

Prove it, by showing the code that you tried already, in your post =) (and remember, "it didn't work" is never a problem description: explain what happened)

What is {s<=1} supposed to mean in the regexp?

What do you mean by "allowing mismatches"?

for pattern in string_patterns: for m in re.finditer(pattern, reference_string): ...

f"({'|'.join(string_patterns)}){{s<=1}}". With PyPi regex, you even have access to named lists.
